# Android: Force close the app in Application class

Tags: android, internet-connection

I have a class which extends Application class. In this class I am checking Internet Connectivity and calling the web service.

Below is the method I am using to check:

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context mContext) {
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connec != null
                && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                || (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

When there is no Internet connection I want to force close the application. How to do it?

I have an alternative solution. If there is no Internet connection, I can skip calling api process and wait for the first activity to start and finish that activity as soon as it starts.

Is it possible to do it in Application class?

Comment: why you force close the application ?? you can simple close/exit the app,

Comment: How can I close/exit the app in an Application class?

Comment: http://androidbasic-answer.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-exit-from-android-application.html

Comment: @Sree I can't call finish() method inside Application class. The link you send is closing app in activity class.

Comment: use flag when exit from the Application class and call finish() in the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you wish to force close an application? Heard of such request for the first time.

When there is no internet, you can just close the activity like this:

```
if (!isInternetConnected(context)){
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Yes I can close the activity but I think you misunderstood me. I am currently in Application class not an activity. I can't call finish() method in Application class.

Answer (score 4):

You can call in Application derived class ;

```
 android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better use this...

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        return true;
    }


   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Internet is not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    alertwifi();
    return false;
}





 public void alertwifi()
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("NO Internet Connection!!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click below to turn on Wifi or Enable Data pack")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Wifi",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    wifi();
                }
              })
               .setNeutralButton("GPRS",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    datapack();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("Back",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing

                    exit();


                }
            });





public void exit()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);
}


// create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```